# @EnableWebMvc showing date in array formate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

We had two application on spring boot. One was spring rest api based & second was spring MVC based.

We have megred both the application due to some business reasons as the context was the same and everything is working fine except java.time.LocalDateTime formatting that does by spring automatically on rest API.
previously it was formatting LocalDateTime as "2018-08-30T18:13:24"
but after merging it is showing as [
2018,
08,
30,
18,
13,
24
],

I have found out @EnableWebMVC annotation is the culprit but after removing that annotation web-mvc pages do not work.

What should I do so that date display in ISO (String) format and view resolver & jsp pages works fine?

Please help thanks.

Comment: I wasted almost a whole day looking at different Jackson configuration alternatives and nothing was working. Thankfully I stumbled upon your post and indeed `@EnableWebMvc` was the culprit.

Answer (score 9):

Everyone is saying @EnableWebMvc is the culprit.
But, no one is saying with **WebMvc** how to resolve this issue.

So, to answer the question, yes, there is a way to resolve this issue by not removing the @EnableWebMvc.

Before moving into the answer, let's understand a few concepts:

- HttpMessageConverters -> These are the ones that convert Java Objects from and to JSON/XML
- By default, Spring boot will add the following converters:

  1. ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter
  2. StringHttpMessageConverter
  3. ResourceHttpMessageConverter
  4. SourceHttpMessageConverter
  5. FormHttpMessageConverter
  6. Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter
  7. MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter
  8. **MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter**
- So, whenever we are converting the java object into JSON, then spring will go through this list of converters one by one in order and picks the relevant one to convert
- Now, if we add our custom MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to this list as the last element, then spring will not come to it because before reaching our converter(9th element), there is the default converter at the 7th index
- So, to resolve this issue, **we need to remove the default MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverte and need to add our custom converter**

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
//        Remove the default MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
        converters.removeIf(converter -> {
            String converterName = converter.getClass().getSimpleName();
            return converterName.equals("MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter");
        });
//        Add your custom MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        converters.add(converter);
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.extendMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Please don't use configureMessageConverters() instead of extendMessageConverters() from WebMvcConfigurer because configure method will remove all the existing converters which will be installed by default.

Hope it will help someone like me who has wasted some hours debugging the issue :)

Comment: Hats off to you and to your professional and scientific explanation. After struggling for hours, this is by far the one-shot perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Jackson** as your JSON <-> POJO mapper, you can set the following properties:

```yaml
spring:
  jackson:
    date-format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
```

`spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps` defaults to `true`, which serializes `LocalDateTime` as an array, like the one you show.

For a finer-grained control, you can also annotate date-time fields like following:

```java
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime datetime;
```

It takes precedence over the above property.

Take a look at other JSON related Spring Boot properties here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#json-properties

Comment: Only this @JsonFormat works but I don't want to go on every dtos and do it.
I want to do it via centralize way.

Comment: Did you define your own `ObjectMapper` bean? If that's the case than this property won't work, but you still can set this configuration in your objectMapper with `objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)`.

Answer (score 0):

For those still facing the issue, `@EnableWebMVC` is definitely the culprit as it disables the Web MVC auto-configuration default behaviors in favor of yours.

About that, the [Spring Boot reference documentation says](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.auto-configuration):

> **Spring MVC Auto-configuration**
> ...
> If you want to take complete control of Spring MVC, you can add your own @Configuration annotated with `@EnableWebMvc` ...

However, you can add custom configuration without losing the default auto-configuration behaviors.

> If you want to **keep** those Spring Boot MVC customizations and **make more MVC customizations** (interceptors, formatters, view controllers, and other features), you can add your own @Configuration class of type WebMvcConfigurer but **without** `@EnableWebMvc`.

That said, **removing @EnableWebMVC should work just fine**.